# Map Array of Form Input Fields with Array of Textarea Value

Tags: jquery, arrays, forms, loops, textarea

I have a array of form fields in my form

```
 <div class="book-form">
  <input type="text" id="book_qty" name="book_qty[0]" value="" >
  <input type="text" id="book_unit" name="book_unit[0]" value="" >
  <input type="text" id="book_name" name="book_name[0]" value="" >
  <input type="text" id="book_notes" name="book_notes[0]" value="" >

  <input type="text" id="book_qty" name="book_qty[1]" value="" >
  <input type="text" id="book_unit" name="book_unit[1]" value="" >
  <input type="text" id="book_name" name="book_name[1]" value="" >
  <input type="text" id="book_notes" name="book_notes[1]" value="" >
 </div>
```

then I have a textarea like this

```
<textarea id="copyFromText">
  1 box Horror without cover
  2 boxes Fiction plain
</textarea>
```

I am trying to loop thru each line of textarea words and copy to form input fields.
I tried with below code and in a normal environment, it works fine

```
  $('#textareaButton').click(function () {
    var all_inputs = $(".book-form input[type=text]");
    for (i = 1; i < all_inputs.length; i++) {
      $.each($('#copyFromText').val().split(' '), function (i, text) {
        all_inputs.eq(i).val(text);

      });
    }
  });
```

The problem is "book_notes" field, while first three fields are mandatory, the note field might or might not have a value.
I assume, I have to make each line of textarea as a separate array (3 words + 1 space field for notes) and copy the words to respective form field. The note field may have more than one spaces.

How do I do this?

Thanks
SAQ